# How to open MATLAB_R2020a through the terminal using a shortened command?

Tags: bash, macos, matlab, terminal, command

I'm currently using this terminal command to open Matlab:

```
open -a MATLAB_R2020a (whenever I'm not in the Applications directory)
```

Does there exist a way to shorten the command? i.e. open Matlab by using the following terminal command:

```
open matlab
```

or

```
open -a matlab
```

Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4.

Comment: Define an `alias` in your `.bashrc` if your terminal uses a `bash` shell (or in an analogous `*rc` file if it uses another shell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start MATLAB by running its startup shell script:

```sh
/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/bin/matlab
```

If you want to shorten this, add the `/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/bin/` directory to your `PATH` environment variable, then you can start MATLAB by just typing `matlab`:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/bin/
matlab
```

The line that starts with `export PATH` can be added to your `~/.profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways, but here is one that I know of which is called **bash scripting**
simply open a new file (lets call it 'thefile.sh' and write the following lines inside;

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a MATLAB_R2020a
```

Then run the following command to make it executable

```
chmod +x thefile.sh
```

now you can simply run

```
./thefile
```

and it will just do that. You will be able to call this command from the directory where it is located, but if you wish to make it accessible from anywhere, just by using terminal, move it to the following location:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

I hope this answers your question.